# android Custom group view doesn't lay out correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I've created this custom view group:

```
public class CustomGroupView extends ViewGroup {

    public static final String TAG = "CustomGroupView";

    public CustomGroupView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomGroupView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomGroupView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure");

        int childrenCount = getChildCount();

        // measure all children
        for(int i=0; i<childrenCount; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        // the height and the width of the overall group view is
        // the height and the width of the last child
        View lastChild = getChildAt(childrenCount-1);
        int overallHeight = lastChild.getMeasuredHeight();
        int overallWidth = lastChild.getMeasuredWidth();

        Log.d(TAG, "overallHeight: " + overallHeight + "; overallWidth: " + overallWidth);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(overallWidth, widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(overallHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLayout");

        Log.d(TAG, "left: " + left + "; top: " + top + "; right: " + right + "; bottom: " + bottom);

        int childrenCount = getChildCount();

        // all children will be aligned to the top
        for(int i=0; i<childrenCount; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            int childLeft = left;
            int childTop = top;
            int childRight = left + child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childBottom = top + child.getMeasuredHeight();

            Log.d("TAG", "child #: " + i + "; left: " + childLeft + "; top: " + childTop + "; right: " + childRight +"; bottom: " + childBottom);

            child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childRight, childBottom);
        }
    }
}
```

and I've found it behaves strangely enough when I place it into LinearLayout container.
Example when it works correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.test.oct9customgroup.CustomGroupView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="#4c4c4c"
            android:scaleX="0.6"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:background="#ffffa3"
            android:scaleX="0.75"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:background="#fce5e8"
            android:scaleX="0.9"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="#b3ffc3"
            android:padding="32dp"
            android:text="Last child's text"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

    </org.test.oct9customgroup.CustomGroupView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Top text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But if I change the order of my custom view group and textview:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <TextView/>

    <org.test.oct9customgroup.CustomGroupView>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </org.test.oct9customgroup.CustomGroupView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Problem:** a big gap appears between that textview and my group view and I don't know how to get rid of it.
Images and logs:
Log when everything works fine:

```
10-09 15:54:08.922 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: onMeasure
10-09 15:54:08.922 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: overallHeight: 144; overallWidth: 800
10-09 15:54:08.924 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: onLayout
10-09 15:54:08.925 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: left: 0; top: 0; right: 800; bottom: 144
10-09 15:54:08.925 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: child #: 0; left: 0; top: 0; right: 800; bottom: 80
10-09 15:54:08.926 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: child #: 1; left: 0; top: 0; right: 800; bottom: 80
10-09 15:54:08.926 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: child #: 2; left: 0; top: 0; right: 800; bottom: 80
10-09 15:54:08.926 18046-18046/org.test.viewsexperiments D/CustomGroupView: child #: 3; left: 0; top: 0; right: 800; bottom: 144
```

Log when the gap appears:

```
10-09 15:59:24.202 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: onMeasure
10-09 15:59:24.202 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: overallHeight: 144; overallWidth: 800
10-09 15:59:24.203 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: onLayout
10-09 15:59:24.204 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: left: 0; top: 90; right: 800; bottom: 234
10-09 15:59:24.204 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: child #: 0; left: 0; top: 90; right: 800; bottom: 170
10-09 15:59:24.204 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: child #: 1; left: 0; top: 90; right: 800; bottom: 170
10-09 15:59:24.204 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: child #: 2; left: 0; top: 90; right: 800; bottom: 170
10-09 15:59:24.205 27506-27506/? D/CustomGroupView: child #: 3; left: 0; top: 90; right: 800; bottom: 234
```

[image: works correctly] [image: gap appears]
Could you please tell me why is this happening?
**Edit** It turns out that the height of the gap equals the height of the TextView which is above my custom group view.
I suppose there's some shift while drawing on a canvas children of my custom group view.
Probably drawing should start from (0, 0), but it starts from (0, top) point.
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

**Edit 2**  After adding red background

```
<org.test.oct9customgroup.CustomGroupView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000">
```

[image: with red background]

Comment: can you give a background color (E.g. red) to your custom ViewGroup?

Comment: @Blackbelt please look at my edit

Comment: the ViewGroup is laid out correctly by its parent than. `int childTop = top;` should be `int childTop = 0`;

Comment: @Blackbelt you are right, could you please post not a comment, but an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `ViewGroup` is laid out correctly by its parent. The mistake is that you need

```
int childTop = 0;
```

instead of

```
int childTop = top;
```

in your `onLayout`. The four values provided by onLayout are relative to the parent

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
```

The four positions is the distance between `CustomGroupView` and its parent, so it makes no sense to use them while layout your children. The code should be:

```
int childLeft = 0;
int childTop = 0;
int childRight = childLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth();
int childBottom = childTop + child.getMeasuredHeight();
```